# Postgres database roles and privileges

Tags: postgresql, privileges, pg-dump

Database role XYZ does not have any privilege.How assign  privileges for that particular role to create a backup of database using pg_dump?

Grant SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN Schema public TO :XYZ

Is it possible to restore the backup with appropriate privilages?

Comment: "*Is it possible?*" - did you try it?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/249172/what-grants-are-required-to-run-pg-dump. The [`pg_dump` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) does unfortunately not cover this, but it appears it generally expects to be run on a superuser connection, see the description of the `--enable-row-security` and `--role` parameters

Comment: Yes, backup will restore with proper privileges -- BUT -- database and role must both exist before `pg_restore` is run. (or the dump redirected to load)

Answer (score 0):

Yes `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO XYZ;` will give XYZ the privilege to create a dump of your database using `pg_dump`, but in order for you to restore the backup (dump) with the appropriate privileges, ensure that you ran the `GRANT` command before making the dump.

Answer (score 0):

First of all YES, the `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO XYZ` will work fine for creating a dump using pg_dump command.

But, ensure that the database, role, and dump must be existing before `pg_restore` is run.